# Выполнение функции по расписанию в Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Веб-приложение не плохо разрослось, и для сокращения обращений к базе хочу запилить кэш некоторых таблиц и время от времени вызывать функцию, которая будет этот кэш обновлять, однако есть одна маленькая неприятность: я не знаю как в приложении Flask вызывать функцию по расписанию, чтобы она не была привязана к конкретному обращению от клиента.

Вот как например в данном коде вызывать функцию cache каждые 20 секунд? Объясните пожалуйста подробно. Заранее благодарю

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def cache():
    somecode()

@app.route('/index.html')
def root():
     return 'page'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать отдельный поток, в него поместить функцию с циклом.

Примерно так:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def cache():
    while True:
        somecode()
        time.sleep(20)

thread = Thread(target=cache)
thread.start()

@app.route('/index.html')
def root():
     return 'page'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```